# Blazor: Setting CSS property on dynamically generated <div> tag of a component

Tags: html, css, blazor, blazor-webassembly

It seems that some of the components, when rendered as HTML, wrap themselves up in a `<div>` tag. For example the **Check** component from [blazorise](https://blazorise.com/) which for the following code:

```
<Check TValue="bool" Style="display: inline;">sample</Check>
```

generates the following html markup:

```
<div class="custom-control custom-checkbox" style=""><!--!-->
    <!--!-->
    <input id="0HM152OSMLP35" type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input" style="display: inline" _bl_9fddd34d-8813-4fa2-939d-819c700124cc=""><!--!-->
    <!--!-->
    <label class="custom-control-label" style="display: inline" for="0HM152OSMLP35"><!--!-->
        sample<!--!-->
    </label><!--!-->
    <!--!-->
    <!--!-->
    <!--!-->
</div>
```

The outer `<div>` tag (`<div class="custom-control custom-checkbox" style="">`) is dynamically generated at runtime.

Now lets say I want to make this component inline, adding the `Style="display: inline;"` to the component, makes the style to be applied for the children elements of the outer `<div>` tag (input and label) but in case of `display: inline`, it does not work and the component is still occupying full width and gets rendered as a block element;

[image: style not applying to the outer div]

Applying `Style="display: inline;"` to the outer `<div>` tag does the trick but how this can be done at the  time of coding?

Comment: It really depends on the specific Component implementation - you'd probably need to raise an issue on the Blazorise GitHub repo

Comment: have you tried simply just adding a css class the same name as used "custom-checkbox" with display: inline in it? you may need !important as well

Comment: @Orak, this way the css would be applied to all `custom-control custom-checkbox` elements and there is no way to differentiate them.

Comment: Have you tried `style` with a lowercase s?

Comment: Yes, the same effect as `Style` with capital s.